# Video face recognition and comparing with the image using Emgu 3.2.0

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, face-recognition, emgucv

dear developers. It's my first time to ask someone here.

Last week I got the **task** from my supervisor: 
To develop the software to compare the visitors' faces appearing on camera with the photos from their member-cards. After a deep research, it seems impossible to complete it with the only one photo, but that's not the point.
I use C# and Emgu library and even wrote the working code but the problem is the accuracy. I tried to use all: "EMGU.CV.EigenFaceRecognizer", "EMGU.CV.FisherFaceRecognizer" and "EMGU.CV.LBPHFaceRecognizer" but all of them make a lot of misrecognition. After I tried to upload 10 photos of my European self and 10 more of my Chinese classmate - it mostly shows my name and only "Eigen Face" is blinking with both of our names seeing him. 
So far I fixed all the errors and bugs myself, but right now there is no even an error and I don't know what to do.
Thank you for your attention.

This is my main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.UI;

namespace Ilovewinforms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        //Load of previus trainned faces and labels for each image
        if (Eigen_Recog.IsTrained)
        {
            message_bar.Text = "Training Data loaded";
        }
        else
        {
            message_bar.Text = "No training data found, please train program using Train menu option";
        }

        Face = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        ENC_Parameters.Param[0] = ENC;
        Image_Encoder_JPG = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            capturecam = new Capture();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
            return;
        }
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(broadcastFunction);
        //Application.Idle += new EventHandler(photoGrabber);
        CapturingProcess = true;
    }

    #region Detection
    #region Detection Variables
    //******************************DETECTION GLOBAL VARIABLES*******************************************//

    Capture capturecam = null; //instance for capture using webcam
    bool CapturingProcess = false; //boolean stating the capturing process status
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imgOrg; //image type RGB (or Bgr as we say in Open CV)    
    Image<Gray, byte> result, TrainedFace = null; //used to store the result image and trained face

    private static readonly CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    //Classifier with default training location
    Classifier_Train Eigen_Recog = new Classifier_Train();

    //MCvFont font = new MCvFont(FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, 0.5); //Our font for writing within the frame
    //CvInvoke.PutText(img, "Hello, world", new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80), FontFace.HersheyComplex, 1.0, new Bgr(0, 255, 0).MCvScalar); //Our font for writing within the frame

    Bitmap[] ExtFaces;
    int faceNo = 0;

    //***************************************************************************************************//
    #endregion

    //Video capture and broadcast
    void broadcastFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgOrg = capturecam.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
        faceDetection(imgOrg);

        //videoPictureBox.Image = imgOrg.ToBitmap();            
        //if (imgOrg == null) return;                   
    }

    void faceDetection(Image<Bgr, Byte> imgOrg)
    {
        //Convert it to Grayscale

        if (imgOrg != null)
        {
            gray_frame = imgOrg.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            //Face Detector
            Rectangle[] facesDetected = Face.DetectMultiScale(gray_frame, 1.2, 10, new Size(50, 50), Size.Empty);

            //Action for each element detected
            Parallel.For(0, facesDetected.Length, i =>
            {
                try
                {
                    facesDetected[i].X += (int)(facesDetected[i].Height * 0.15);
                    facesDetected[i].Y += (int)(facesDetected[i].Width * 0.22);
                    facesDetected[i].Height -= (int)(facesDetected[i].Height * 0.3);
                    facesDetected[i].Width -= (int)(facesDetected[i].Width * 0.35);

                    result = imgOrg.Copy(facesDetected[i]).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
                    result._EqualizeHist();
                    //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                    imgOrg.Draw(facesDetected[i], new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);

                    if (Eigen_Recog.IsTrained)
                    {
                        string name = Eigen_Recog.Recognise(result);
                        int match_value = (int)Eigen_Recog.Get_Eigen_Distance;

                        //Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
                        //imgOrg.Draw(name + " ", ref font, new Point(facesDetected[i].X - 2, facesDetected[i].Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));
                        CvInvoke.PutText(imgOrg, name + " ", new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80), FontFace.HersheyComplex, 1.0, new Bgr(255, 0, 0).MCvScalar);
                        ADD_Face_Found(result, name, match_value);
                    }

                }
                catch
                {
                    //do nothing as parrellel loop buggy
                    //No action as the error is useless, it is simply an error in 
                    //no data being there to process and this occurss sporadically 
                }
            });
            //Show the faces procesed and recognized
            videoPictureBox.Image = imgOrg.ToBitmap();
        }
    }

    //ADD Picture box and label to a panel for each face
    int faces_count = 0;
    int faces_panel_Y = 0;
    int faces_panel_X = 0;

    void Clear_Faces_Found()
    {
        this.Faces_Found_Panel.Controls.Clear();
        faces_count = 0;
        faces_panel_Y = 0;
        faces_panel_X = 0;
    }

    void ADD_Face_Found(Image<Gray, Byte> img_found, string name_person, int match_value)
    {
        PictureBox PI = new PictureBox();
        PI.Location = new Point(faces_panel_X, faces_panel_Y);
        PI.Height = 80;
        PI.Width = 80;
        PI.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        PI.Image = img_found.ToBitmap();
        Label LB = new Label();
        LB.Text = name_person + " " + match_value.ToString();
        LB.Location = new Point(faces_panel_X, faces_panel_Y + 80);
        LB.Width = 80;
        LB.Height = 15;

        Faces_Found_Panel.Controls.Add(PI);
        Faces_Found_Panel.Controls.Add(LB);
        faces_count++;
        if (faces_count == 2)
        {
            faces_panel_X = 0;
            faces_panel_Y += 100;
            faces_count = 0;
        }
        else faces_panel_X += 85;

        if (Faces_Found_Panel.Controls.Count > 10)
        {
            Clear_Faces_Found();
        }

    }
    #endregion


    #region Training

    #region Training Variables
    //******************************RECOGNITION GLOBAL VARIABLES*****************************************//  

    Image<Gray, byte> gray_frame = null;

    //Classifier
    CascadeClassifier Face = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

    //Saving Jpg
    List<Image<Gray, byte>> ImagestoWrite = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
    EncoderParameters ENC_Parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    EncoderParameter ENC = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100);
    ImageCodecInfo Image_Encoder_JPG;

    //Saving XAML Data file
    List<string> NamestoWrite = new List<string>();
    List<string> NamesforFile = new List<string>();
    XmlDocument docu = new XmlDocument();

    //Variables
    Form1 Parent;
    private Image<Bgr, byte> img;

    //For aquiring 10 images in a row
    List<Image<Gray, byte>> resultImages = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
    int results_list_pos = 0;
    int num_faces_to_aquire = 10;
    bool RECORD = false;

    //***************************************************************************************************//
    #endregion
    void photoGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the current frame form capture device
        //currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

        // Converting the master image to a bitmap
        Bitmap masterImage = (Bitmap)photoPictureBox.Image;

        // Normalizing it to grayscale
        img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(masterImage);

        //Convert it to Grayscale
        if (img != null)
        {
            gray_frame = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

            //Face Detector
            //MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray_frame.DetectHaarCascade(Face, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20)); //old method
            Rectangle[] facesDetected = Face.DetectMultiScale(gray_frame, 1.2, 10, new Size(50, 50), Size.Empty);

            //Action for each element detected
            for (int i = 0; i < facesDetected.Length; i++)// (Rectangle face_found in facesDetected)
            {
                //This will focus in on the face from the haar results its not perfect but it will remove a majoriy
                //of the background noise
                facesDetected[i].X += (int)(facesDetected[i].Height * 0.15);
                facesDetected[i].Y += (int)(facesDetected[i].Width * 0.22);
                facesDetected[i].Height -= (int)(facesDetected[i].Height * 0.3);
                facesDetected[i].Width -= (int)(facesDetected[i].Width * 0.35);

                result = img.Copy(facesDetected[i]).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
                result._EqualizeHist();
                facePictureBox.Image = result.ToBitmap();
                //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                img.Draw(facesDetected[i], new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);

            }      

            photoPictureBox.Image = img.ToBitmap();
        }
    }

    private bool save_training_data(Image face_data)
    {
        try
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            bool file_create = true;
            string facename = "face_" + nameTextBox.Text + "_" + rand.Next().ToString() + ".jpg";
            while (file_create)
            {

                if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + facename))
                {
                    file_create = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    facename = "face_" + nameTextBox.Text + "_" + rand.Next().ToString() + ".jpg";
                }
            }


            if (Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/"))
            {
                face_data.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + facename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/");
                face_data.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + facename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml"))
            {
                //File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt", NAME_PERSON.Text + "\n\r");
                bool loading = true;
                while (loading)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        docu.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml");
                        loading = false;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        docu = null;
                        docu = new XmlDocument();
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                }

                //Get the root element
                XmlElement root = docu.DocumentElement;

                XmlElement face_D = docu.CreateElement("FACE");
                XmlElement name_D = docu.CreateElement("NAME");
                XmlElement file_D = docu.CreateElement("FILE");

                //Add the values for each nodes
                //name.Value = textBoxName.Text;
                //age.InnerText = textBoxAge.Text;
                //gender.InnerText = textBoxGender.Text;
                name_D.InnerText = nameTextBox.Text;
                file_D.InnerText = facename;

                //Construct the Person element
                //person.Attributes.Append(name);
                face_D.AppendChild(name_D);
                face_D.AppendChild(file_D);

                //Add the New person element to the end of the root element
                root.AppendChild(face_D);

                //Save the document
                docu.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml");
                //XmlElement child_element = docu.CreateElement("FACE");
                //docu.AppendChild(child_element);
                //docu.Save("TrainedLabels.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                FileStream FS_Face = File.OpenWrite(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml");
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FS_Face))
                {
                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("Faces_For_Training");

                    writer.WriteStartElement("FACE");
                    writer.WriteElementString("NAME", nameTextBox.Text);
                    writer.WriteElementString("FILE", facename);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
                }
                FS_Face.Close();
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }        

    //Delete all the old training data by simply deleting the folder
    private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/"))
        {
            Directory.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/", true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/");
        }
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (resultImages.Count == num_faces_to_aquire)
        //{
            if (!save_training_data(facePictureBox.Image))
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error in saving file info. Training data not saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        //}

    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the faces training class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Face;

using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Desingned to remove the training a EigenObjectRecognizer code from the main form
/// </summary>
class Classifier_Train : IDisposable
{

    #region Variables

    //Eigen
    //EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer;
    FaceRecognizer recognizer;

    //training variables
    List<Image<Gray, byte>> trainingImages = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();//Images
    //TODO: see if this can be combined in Ditionary format this will remove support for old data
    List<string> Names_List = new List<string>(); //labels
    List<int> Names_List_ID = new List<int>();
    int ContTrain, NumLabels;
    float Eigen_Distance = 0;
    string Eigen_label;
    int Eigen_threshold = 2000;

    //Class Variables
    string Error;
    bool _IsTrained = false;

    //"EMGU.CV.EigenFaceRecognizer"
    //"EMGU.CV.FisherFaceRecognizer"
    //"EMGU.CV.LBPHFaceRecognizer"

    public string Recognizer_Type = "EMGU.CV.EigenFaceRecognizer";
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor, Looks in (Application.StartupPath + "\\TrainedFaces") for traing data.
    /// </summary>
    public Classifier_Train()
    {
        _IsTrained = LoadTrainingData(Application.StartupPath + "\\TrainedFaces");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Takes String input to a different location for training data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Training_Folder"></param>
    public Classifier_Train(string Training_Folder)
    {
        _IsTrained = LoadTrainingData(Training_Folder);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrains the recognizer witout resetting variables like recognizer type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Retrain()
    {
        return _IsTrained = LoadTrainingData(Application.StartupPath + "\\TrainedFaces");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrains the recognizer witout resetting variables like recognizer type.
    /// Takes String input to a different location for training data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Retrain(string Training_Folder)
    {
        return _IsTrained = LoadTrainingData(Training_Folder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Return(True): If Training data has been located and Eigen Recogniser has been trained</para>
    /// <para>Return(False): If NO Training data has been located of error in training has occured</para>
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsTrained
    {
        get { return _IsTrained; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recognise a Grayscale Image using the trained Eigen Recogniser
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Input_image"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string Recognise(Image<Gray, byte> Input_image, int Eigen_Thresh = -1)
    {
        if (_IsTrained)
        {
            FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult ER = recognizer.Predict(Input_image);

            if (ER.Label == -1)
            {
                Eigen_label = "Unknown";
                Eigen_Distance = 0;
                return Eigen_label;
            }
            else
            {
                Eigen_label = Names_List[ER.Label];
                Eigen_Distance = (float)ER.Distance;
                if (Eigen_Thresh > -1) Eigen_threshold = Eigen_Thresh;

                //Only use the post threshold rule if we are using an Eigen Recognizer 
                //since Fisher and LBHP threshold set during the constructor will work correctly 
                switch (Recognizer_Type)
                {
                    case ("EMGU.CV.EigenFaceRecognizer"):
                        if (Eigen_Distance > Eigen_threshold) return Eigen_label;
                        else return "Unknown";
                    case ("EMGU.CV.FisherFaceRecognizer"):
                    case ("EMGU.CV.LBPHFaceRecognizer"):
                    default:
                        return Eigen_label; //the threshold set in training controls unknowns
                }




            }

        }
        else return "";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string containg the recognised persons name
    /// </summary>
    public string Get_Eigen_Label
    {
        get
        {
            return Eigen_label;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a float confidence value for potential false clasifications
    /// </summary>
    public float Get_Eigen_Distance
    {
        get
        {
            //get eigenDistance
            return Eigen_Distance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a string contatining any error that has occured
    /// </summary>
    public string Get_Error
    {
        get { return Error; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose of Class call Garbage Collector
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        recognizer = null;
        trainingImages = null;
        Names_List = null;
        Error = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the traing data given a (string) folder location
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Folder_location"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool LoadTrainingData(string Folder_location)
    {
        if (File.Exists(Folder_location + "\\TrainedLabels.xml"))
        {
            try
            {
                //message_bar.Text = "";
                Names_List.Clear();
                Names_List_ID.Clear();
                trainingImages.Clear();
                FileStream filestream = File.OpenRead(Folder_location + "\\TrainedLabels.xml");
                long filelength = filestream.Length;
                byte[] xmlBytes = new byte[filelength];
                filestream.Read(xmlBytes, 0, (int)filelength);
                filestream.Close();

                MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes);

                using (XmlReader xmlreader = XmlTextReader.Create(xmlStream))
                {
                    while (xmlreader.Read())
                    {
                        if (xmlreader.IsStartElement())
                        {
                            switch (xmlreader.Name)
                            {
                                case "NAME":
                                    if (xmlreader.Read())
                                    {
                                        Names_List_ID.Add(Names_List.Count); //0, 1, 2, 3....
                                        Names_List.Add(xmlreader.Value.Trim());
                                        NumLabels += 1;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "FILE":
                                    if (xmlreader.Read())
                                    {
                                        //PROBLEM HERE IF TRAININGG MOVED
                                        trainingImages.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(Application.StartupPath + "\\TrainedFaces\\" + xmlreader.Value.Trim()));
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ContTrain = NumLabels;

                if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
                {

                    //Eigen face recognizer
                    //Parameters:   
                    //      num_components – The number of components (read: Eigenfaces) kept for this Prinicpal 
                    //          Component Analysis. As a hint: There’s no rule how many components (read: Eigenfaces) 
                    //          should be kept for good reconstruction capabilities. It is based on your input data, 
                    //          so experiment with the number. Keeping 80 components should almost always be sufficient.
                    //
                    //      threshold – The threshold applied in the prediciton. This still has issues as it work inversly to LBH and Fisher Methods.
                    //          if you use 0.0 recognizer.Predict will always return -1 or unknown if you use 5000 for example unknow won't be reconised.
                    //          As in previous versions I ignore the built in threhold methods and allow a match to be found i.e. double.PositiveInfinity
                    //          and then use the eigen distance threshold that is return to elliminate unknowns. 
                    //
                    //NOTE: The following causes the confusion, sinc two rules are used. 
                    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    //Eigen Uses
                    //          0 - X = unknown
                    //          > X = Recognised
                    //
                    //Fisher and LBPH Use
                    //          0 - X = Recognised
                    //          > X = Unknown
                    //
                    // Where X = Threshold value


                    switch (Recognizer_Type)
                    {
                        case ("EMGU.CV.LBPHFaceRecognizer"):
                            recognizer = new LBPHFaceRecognizer(1, 8, 8, 8, 100);//50
                            break;
                        case ("EMGU.CV.FisherFaceRecognizer"):
                            recognizer = new FisherFaceRecognizer(0, 3500);//4000
                            break;
                        case ("EMGU.CV.EigenFaceRecognizer"):
                        default:
                            recognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(80, double.PositiveInfinity);
                            break;
                    }

                    recognizer.Train(trainingImages.ToArray(), Names_List_ID.ToArray());
                    // Recognizer_Type = recognizer.GetType();
                    // string v = recognizer.ToString(); //EMGU.CV.FisherFaceRecognizer || EMGU.CV.EigenFaceRecognizer || EMGU.CV.LBPHFaceRecognizer

                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error = ex.ToString();
                return false;
            }
        }
        else return false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: "but right now there is no even an error and I don't know what to do" - With only one Foto each, I guess that's as good as it gets.

Comment: I pointed that I made an experiment with 10 pictures for each, and it still makes mistakes.